# HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed Django

Tags: django, web, post, get, http-status-code-405

I am trying to create an APIView (path 'create-room' in urls.py) where I can either edit a Room model if the session already exists or create a new Room model if the session doesn't exist. In the APIView, [this is what I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JC6NT.png).
I don't know why it's saying `GET /api/create-room`, which is causing the error of `HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed`.
How do I change the request to a POST request, as [shown in the tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkpuL.png) (written `POST /api/create-room` instead of `GET`

Heres my code:

```
# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import generics, status
from .serializers import RoomSerializer, CreateRoomSerializer
from .models import Room
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

# Create your views here.


class RoomView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Room.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RoomSerializer

# The problematic API View
class CreateRoomView(APIView):
    serializer_class = CreateRoomSerializer

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        if not self.request.session.exists(self.request.session.session_key):
            self.request.session.create()

        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            guest_can_pause = serializer.data.get('guest_can_pause')
            votes_to_skip = serializer.data.get('votes_to_skip')
            host = self.request.session.session_key
            # Check if host already has a session
            queryset = Room.objects.filter(host=host)
            if queryset.exists():
                room = queryset[0]
                room.guest_can_pause = guest_can_pause
                room.votes_to_skip = votes_to_skip
                room.save(update_fields=['guest_can_pause', 'votes_to_skip'])
                return Response(RoomSerializer(room).data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                room = Room(host=host, guest_can_pause=guest_can_pause,
                            votes_to_skip=votes_to_skip)
                room.save()
                return Response(RoomSerializer(room).data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response({'Bad Request': 'Invalid data...'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

```
# serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Room

class RoomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Room
        fields = ('id', 'code', 'host', 'guest_can_pause',
                  'votes_to_skip', 'created_at')

class CreateRoomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Room
        fields = ('guest_can_pause', 'votes_to_skip')
```

```
# urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

# URLConf
urlpatterns = [
    path('room', views.RoomView.as_view()),
    path('create-room', views.CreateRoomView.as_view())
]
```

I have tried adding this block of code to my view

```
def get(self, request, format=None):
    queryset = Room.objects.all()
    serializer = self.serializer_class()
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

But the request is a GET request, and when I try to make a POST request on the API view, it loads forever:
[This is where I try to make a POST request that loads forever](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39OBu.png)

Comment: Please provide more information about how exactly you make the requests, not just links to images. Also include the server side logs if they contain any useful information.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer is useful to you

```
# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import generics, status
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError

from .serializers import RoomSerializer, CreateRoomSerializer
from .models import Room
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response



# class RoomView(generics.ListAPIView):
#    queryset = Room.objects.all()
#    #serializer_class = RoomSerializer
#    serializers = CreateRoomSerializer

# The problematic API View
class RoomAPIView(APIView):
    serializer_class = RoomSerializer

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        queryset = Room.objects.all()
        data = RoomSerializer(data=queryset, many=True)

        return Response(data=data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        if not self.request.session.exists(self.request.session.session_key):
            self.request.session.create()

        serializer = CreateRoomSerializer(data=request.data)

        try:
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        except ValidationError:
            return Response({'Bad Request': 'Invalid data...'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        # Check if host already has a session
        host = self.request.session.session_key

        room, is_created = Room.objects.update_or_create(
            host=host,
            defaults={
                "guest_can_pause": serializer.data['guest_can_pause'],
                "votes_to_skip": serializer.data['votes_to_skip'],
            },
        )

        return Response(
            data=RoomSerializer(room).data,
            status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
        )

        # serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        # if serializer.is_valid():
        #     guest_can_pause = serializer.data.get('guest_can_pause')
        #     votes_to_skip = serializer.data.get('votes_to_skip')
        #     host = self.request.session.session_key
        #     # Check if host already has a session
        #     queryset = Room.objects.filter(host=host)
        #     if queryset.exists():
        #         room = queryset[0]
        #         room.guest_can_pause = guest_can_pause
        #         room.votes_to_skip = votes_to_skip
        #         room.save(update_fields=['guest_can_pause', 'votes_to_skip'])
        #         return Response(RoomSerializer(room).data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        #     else:
        #         room = Room(host=host, guest_can_pause=guest_can_pause,
        #                     votes_to_skip=votes_to_skip)
        #         room.save()
        #         return Response(RoomSerializer(room).data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        #
        # return Response({'Bad Request': 'Invalid data...'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

recommend to unify APIView into one

```
# urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

# URLConf
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/rooms/', views.RoomAPIView.as_view()),
]
```

you can see api docs in link http://localhost:8000/api/rooms/ GET & POST

Comment: Thanks. This works, but now when I try to make a post request, it still loads infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, when i try to click the post button it takes for ever ...

after that i found out in my models.py that i had an infinite loop, cause i basically forgot to check if exist() == false

before

```
def generate_unique_code():
    length = 6

    while True:
        code = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=length))
        if Room.objects.filter(code=code).exists():
            break
        
        return code
```

I fixed it by doing this :

```
def generate_unique_code():
    length = 6

    while True:
        code = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=length))
        if Room.objects.filter(code=code).exists() == False:
            break
        
        return code
```